# MapKit adding multiple annotations from core data

Tags: swift, core-data, mapkit, ios9, mapkitannotation

This is my code.  It loops for the number records in the database but only retrieves the first records lat and lon.

```
    func fetch() {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mappoints")
    let fetchResults = try! context.executeFetchRequest(freq) as! [NSManagedObject]
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    myData = fetchResults
    myData.count
    for _ in myData  {
        let data: NSManagedObject = myData[row]

    lat = (data.valueForKey("latitude") as? String)!
    lon = (data.valueForKey("longitude") as? String)!

    let latNumb = (lat as NSString).doubleValue
    let longNumb = (lon as NSString).doubleValue
    let signLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latNumb, longNumb)
    addAnnotaion(signLocation)
    }

}
```

I am sure I am missing something simple but just keep missing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I ended up with to fix the issue.

```
    func fetch() {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mappoints")
    let fetchResults = try! context.executeFetchRequest(freq) as! [NSManagedObject]
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    myData = fetchResults
    let ct = myData.count // Add this line
    // Then changed the for statement from for _ in myData
    // To the line below and now all map points show up.
    for row in 0...ct-1 {
        let data: NSManagedObject = myData[row]
        lat = (data.valueForKey("latitude") as? String)!
        lon = (data.valueForKey("longitude") as? String)!
        let latNumb = (lat as NSString).doubleValue
        let longNumb = (lon as NSString).doubleValue
        let signLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latNumb, longNumb)
        addAnnotaion(signLocation)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop looks weird. You say `myData[row]`, but you don't seem to increment the row. If the row does not increment, the `data` variable will always be the same.

You could do for example `for data in myData { ...`