# How can I add multiple annotations on a map using GPS coordinates with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, gps, annotations, swift2

I am new to Swift. I was following a tutorial to make an annotation on a map. I successfully made one annotation, thats as far as the tutorial went... I've been looking around trying to find how to make multiple annotations using Swift and can't find it.

How can I make multiple annotations on the map?
Thanks.

***Here is my code from viewcontroller.swift:***

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //setting the map region
        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 33.606800
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = -111.845360
        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        //map annotation
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "Taliesin West"
        annotation.subtitle = "Design"
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)        

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: See this as a starting point. [Adding multiple annotaions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938044/mapkit-adding-multiple-annotations-from-core-data)  you can also check to this one [Tutorial](http://rshankar.com/how-to-add-mapview-annotation-and-draw-polyline-in-swift/). Also this was a one min search to find these.  Please give it a try and then show your code that is not working.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This looks very different than what I have.

Comment: Should I paste this over what I have or and do this for each annotation or add this to the code I currently have? The next annotation I plan on making is: Fallingwater Latitude 39.906299 Longitude -79.467794

Comment: The next question I have is where will your annotations be coming from? There are several different ways this can be done. Also which is very different? I gave you two different links. Both where meant to give you different approaches on this question.

Comment: I got my annotations coordinates using Google Maps. I looked at both examples in greater detail, learned about the plist and then did the tutorial version. The only thing preventing the app from running is the first line of code under the step Add annotation to MapKit.  func getMapAnnotations() -&gt; [Station] {
//  The error messages are saying: Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' , Expected '{' in body of function declaration, and Expected declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another annotation like the example does and call

```
map.addAnnotation(another)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The next annotation I plan on making is: Fallingwater Latitude 39.906299 Longitude -79.467794. I'm currently not at a computer. Part of what I was struggling with is the Latitude and Longitude for the second location. Is this how the second annotation should look?                                                                                                   let another = MKPointAnnotation()
        another.coordinate = locationTwo = (39.906299, -79.467794) 
        another.title = "Fallingwater"
        another.subtitle = "Design"
        map.addAnnotation(another)